# Gazebo9 - ROS Kinetic - packages?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,
since 25.01.2018 Gazebo9 is available. Anyone of you installed it yet and used it with ROS-**Kinetic**?

Currently I am not able to use it.... I get this error: Ressource not found gazebo_ros

It seems like the ROS-Kinetic packages for gazebo9 are not available yet:
[image: image description]

Greetings
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281709/gazebo9---ros-kinetic---packages?/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2018-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update 2018-02-15: packages for Gazebo 9 are now available ([discourse announcement](https://discourse.ros.org/t/gazebo9-ros-kinetic-lunar-wrappers-available/3975)).

---

The default version of Gazebo will always remain `7` for ROS Kinetic, as per [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021).

If you want to install a different version of Gazebo, you may follow the [Which combination of ROS/Gazebo versions to use](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions) tutorial on the `gazebosim.org` site. It's a bit hidden, but the procedure is basically:

1. add `packages.osrfoundation.org` repository
2. install `ros-kinetic-gazebo9-ros-pkgs`

I'm not sure the OSRF repository already contains packages for Gazebo 9 though.

Note that you may run into issues with packages that expect/require Gazebo 7 (ie: Kinetics default version).

---

An alternative could be to use one of the available [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/gazebo/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-02-03**:
Well I guess: the current problem is: **ros-kinetic-gazebo9-ros-pkgs** are not available yet!